# Elasticsearch delete a document based on a field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and trying to figure out a way to delete a document that contains a field with timestamp as its value.

I have a document with a field called **lastmodifiedtime**. This field is of type long and is being used to store the timestamp (i.e number of milliseconds since EPOCH. ex, 1486709502).

Now I have a usecase where I need to delete all the documents that are having lastmodifiedtime older than one day. So I find out the timstamp value corresponding to the one day older time and then try to delete the documents.

I tried REST call as below

```
DELETE http://localhost:9200/testindex/testtype/_query
"query": {
    "term" : {
        "lastmodifiedtime" : {
        "lte": 1486709504
        }
    }
 }
```

But getting the following response:

```
{
    "found": false,
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "testtype",
    "_id": "_query",
    "_version": 4,
    "result": "not_found",
    "_shards":
    {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    }
}
```

Could you please help me how to deal with this scenario?

Comment: This just means that your query is not returning any matches. Are you sure documents exist (just run a query for documents lastmodifiedtime lte 1486709504 and check if it returns results.

Comment: If you are using >= 5.2 of elasticsearch try this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Comment: `1486709504` is the number of seconds, `1486709504000` is the number of milliseconds. Try it out.

Comment: @rad11: This is elasticsearch 5.2.2 and I did try delete by query api too. But no luck.

Comment: @Val : My bad. The value stored in document is 1486709504 and I am trying to query using similar value.

Comment: @i.net: The document does exists and returns in the result when I query with _search. For simplicity, I have only one document in this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [delete_by](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) query api

```
POST http://localhost:9200/testindex/testtype/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "lastmodifiedtime": {
        "lte": 1486709504
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this but no luck :(. Getting the following error: 

    {
        "error":
        {
            "root_cause":
            [
                {
                    "type": "parse_exception",
                    "reason": "Failed to derive xcontent"
                }
            ],
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to derive xcontent"
        },
        "status": 400
    }

Comment: ahh,,, are you trying to do a range query?

Comment: i have edited my answer, this should work now for you

Comment: glad this worked for you, can you please accept this answer as correct